# postfix configuration to verify all recipients

Tags: users, email, postfix, verification

I have a mail server that should receive all mails, even if no user exists.
My big problem is the: Postfix Address Verification like mentioned here: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html

Servers that use that kind of recipient verification won't send me mails if there is no user to receive these mails.

As mentioned in the Postfix Readme, to verify a recipient, the server is sending a probe message to my server, to check if a user exists.

My goal is to find a way to always reply to those probe messages with the right answer to tell all servers that the user they are looking for exists.

Is there anything special in the settings I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mail server needs to accept and deliver mail for all addresses in your domain(s) whether they "exist" or not, then it needs to be configured to do so.  As soon as it is, then it will immediately start providing the right responses to any remote servers doing recipient verification.

Exactly how to do this depends on many factors, but the two most common cases are delivering to local domains (i.e. domains listed in `mydestination`) and delivering to virtual domains (e.g. listed in a `virtual_alias_maps` database).

1. To accept all mail for any address at any domain listed in `mydestination`, you need to set the `luser_relay` in your /etc/postfix/main.cf to tell postfix where mail for unknown recipients should be delivered.  e.g. if you have a local account called 'catchall' then set `luser_relay = catchall+$local`.  The mail will be delivered to catchall's mailbox.
2. To accept all mail for a virtual domain, then you need a catchall alias in the virtualtable.  e.g. to deliver all mail for all unknown users "@virtual.example.com" to "admin@example.com":

```
      fred@virtual.example.com   fred@example.com
      joe@virtual.example.com    joe@somewhere.else.example.com
      @virtual.example.com       admin@example.com
```

Mail for "fred" and "joe" will be delivered as specified, while mail for all other addresses "@virtual.example.com" will be delivered to "admin@example.com".

Comment: i can't even remember if `my_destination` with an underscore was the correct spelling back in 2013 or if i made a typo when writing this answer, but @sphakka is correct that it's certainly `mydestination` without an underscore these days.